# History of operation on windows

Tags: windows-xp, history, logging

Is there a way to determine what the last operations performed on a windows XP machine, including the opening of files, applications, and any and all file manipulations (copy, cut paste) etc... ?

Comment: This type of investigation is usually called "forensics". You will find a lot of information in Google using that term.

Comment: I also think (if set) there are some auditing service tools under the administrative tool in the control panel that you may be able to use to view such info.. (Been a while since i used windows so can't be exactly sure)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [windows event logs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  for details

Comment: event log contains only that info that is specifically logged there. You won't find info of all the open/accessed files there.

Comment: @Vikram File system accesses are  audited based on Security ACLs set on file objects. These audited file system accesses are recorded in security event log

Comment: Thats fine, if auditing is turned on. Usually it is not. If auditing is not turned on, there won't be a record. The question also asked about cut/paste, for which I believe there is no way to get this information.